# How to click select id value?

Tags: javascript

Here is the HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="price">
 $20
</span>
<p id="in-carHEREt" style="display: none;">in cartHERE</p>
 <span class="needsclick select-widget  enabled" id="size-options-link">Medium</span>
 <select id="size-options" name="size-options" class="select-widget ">
<option value="46158">Medium</option>    
<option value="46159">Large</option>    
 <option value="46160">XLarge</option>    
</select>

 <span id="cart-update"><span class="cart-button">add to cart</span></span>
```

I tried the following but it won't change the option, stuck at 'Medium'.

```
document.getElementById("size-options").value = "Large"
document.getElementById("size-options").dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))

document.getElementById("size-options-link").dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))
document.getElementById("size-options-link").value = "Large"
```

I don't know how to select Large.

Any help is appreciated, I need the answer to be like the above as I am using it in a function in swift called evaluatejavascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments inline:

```js
// Get all the options into an array
let options = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#size-options > option"));

// Use Array.filter() to locate just the one with the text of "Large"
let large = options.filter(function(item){
  return item.textContent === "Large";
});

// Get the value of that item and set that as the <select> value
document.getElementById("size-options").value = large[0].value;

document.getElementById("size-options").dispatchEvent(new Event('change')) // Fire the change event
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="price">$20</span>
<p id="in-carHEREt" style="display: none;">in cartHERE</p>
<span class="needsclick select-widget  enabled" id="size-options-link">Medium</span>
<select id="size-options" name="size-options" class="select-widget ">
  <option value="46158">Medium</option>    
  <option value="46159">Large</option>    
  <option value="46160">XLarge</option>    
</select>

<span id="cart-update"><span class="cart-button">add to cart</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mistakenly set the Display Text of the `<option>` instead of its value. You have to set 46159 as value.

```
document.getElementById("size-options").value = "46159"
document.getElementById("size-options").dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
```

Comment: what if I don't know the value? How would I do it then? Also this doesn't change the selection.

Comment: @Andrew Do you know the Display Text? For example "Large"?

Comment: yes I know the Display Text. Sadly your code doesn't change the selection :(

Comment: In this case, you need a mapping json to get the value based on the corresponding Display Text. Like var mapping = {'Large': 46159}. You can get it as follows. mapping["Large"]